# Cannot ssh into terraform deployment

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform

I'm following this `terraform` tutorial found at [gruntwork.io](https://blog.gruntwork.io/an-introduction-to-terraform-f17df9c6d180). I can use `$ terraform apply` to spin up a virtual machine, which shows in the aws console with a public facing ip address and everything. Unfortunately the instance seems to be attached to a previously defined security group and doesn't seems to be responding to `ssh` or `curl` as l might expect.

I've modified the security group so that the proper ports are open, and modified the tutorials `main.tf` file in an attempt to add a user account that l can use to at least see what's running on the vm with.

The results of `terraform apply` can be seen [here](https://pastebin.com/5TnU1BNR)
When l try to ssh into the instance with the test user and the associated private key l get a response of permission denied (this also happens if l try logging in as the default user, `ubuntu`). What am l misunderstanding that the security groups aren't being defined properly and that the user isn't being added to the instance properly. The tutorial was written for terraform 0.7, and l'm running with 0.11.10, but l can't imagine that something so basic would change.

The modified `main.tf` file is as follows

```
# ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
# DEPLOY A SINGLE EC2 INSTANCE
# This template uses runs a simple "Hello, World" web server on a single EC2 Instance
# ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

# ------------------------------------------------------------------------------
# CONFIGURE OUR AWS CONNECTION
# ------------------------------------------------------------------------------

provider "aws" {
  region = "us-east-1"

}

# ---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
# DEPLOY A SINGLE EC2 INSTANCE
# ---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

resource "aws_instance" "example" {
  # Ubuntu Server 14.04 LTS (HVM), SSD Volume Type in us-east-1
  ami = "ami-2d39803a"
  instance_type = "t2.micro"
  vpc_security_group_ids = ["${aws_security_group.instance.id}"]

  user_data = <<-EOF
              #!/bin/bash
              echo "Hello, World" > index.html
              nohup busybox httpd -f -p "${var.server_port}" &
              EOF
  tags {
    Name = "terraform-example"
  }
}

# ---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
# CREATE THE SECURITY GROUP THAT'S APPLIED TO THE EC2 INSTANCE
# ---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

resource "aws_security_group" "instance" {
  name = "terraform-example-instance"

  # Inbound HTTP from anywhere
  ingress {
    from_port = "${var.server_port}"
    to_port = "${var.server_port}"
    protocol = "tcp"
    cidr_blocks = ["0.0.0.0/0"]
  }
  # Inbound SSH from anywhere
  ingress {
    from_port = "22"
    to_port = "22"
    protocol = "tcp"
    cidr_blocks = ["0.0.0.0/0"]
  }
}

variable "server_port" {
  description = "The port the server will user for the HTTP requests"
  default = 8080
}

# ---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
# Try to add a user to the spun up machine that we can ssh into the account of
# ---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

resource "aws_iam_user" "user" {
  name = "test-user"
  path = "/"
}

resource "aws_iam_user_ssh_key" "user" {
  username = "${aws_iam_user.user.name}"
  encoding = "SSH"
  public_key = <public_key>
}
```

Comment: Have you verified that you are using the correct key pair with the correct user? By default, the user for an ubuntu ec2 instance is "ubuntu".

Comment: I did try logging in as ubuntu. Still no dice

Answer (score 1):

You did not specify any keypair name while creating ec2 instance.
For using ubuntu user for ssh you should specify keypair name